# Pass by reference for recursive function in matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion, pass-by-reference

I am performing a region growing algorithm and have a struct array `A` containing a struct `a` which contain a field called `nodes`. I am passing A through a recursive function `grow_a` where given a condition, `a.nodes` gets appended by new nodes. The function is called as:

```
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    % each element of the struct array
    this_a = A(i).a;
    % neighbors contain the neighbors of each node
    % A is changed in the function
    [a,A] = grow_a(this_a,i,neighbors,A);
    % print a
end
```

The `grow_a` function is given by:

```
function [this_a,A] = grow_a(this_a,node,neighbors,A)
    for i = 1:size(neighbors,2)
         neighbor = neighbors(node,i);
         b = A(neighbor).a;
         % auxilary function to see if the elements are similar
         if(issame(this_a,b))
              this_a.nodes = [this_a.nodes b.nodes];
              A(neighbor).a = [];
              [this_a,A] = grow_a(this_a,neighbor,neighbors,A);
         end
    end
end
```

The problem is that during recursion, the nodes added to `this_a` does not stay after the recursion and only the last pass (of the `i` element) is returned. I am assuming that this is happening due to the function passing the elements by value rather than by reference (I could be wrong). So my question is two-fold:

1. Am I correct in assuming that pass-by-reference would rectify this situation?
2. If so, how can I convert this to be pass-by reference?

Thank you for your help.

Edit: 
a is a struct containing following info:
params - [3x1] matrix - parameters of segments

nodes - number of nodes contained in the region - starts with the node in A

A - all the nodes (seeds of the region)

issame - function which compares parameters and returns 1 if segments are same or 0 if segments are different

Comment: Could You provide an example of Your structure A?

Comment: E.g. - A is a 1000x1 struct array with struct `a` having field `nodes`.

Comment: Great, but we are still lacking reproductibility so it's kinda unlike we will find a solution.

Comment: Ah I am sorry about that. Added it as edit.

Comment: Ok. I would be more clear. Could you post the code which should work. With all defined variables. Just use some dummy initialization. It is really hard to detect problems in a code which could not work, as we have not enough input